# How to group the values with specific difference in R?

Tags: r, grouping

In the vector, I want to group some values with specific differences.

(raw data)

```
c(475.37939453125, 476.381774902344, 477.387451171875, 619.419372558594, 
620.4248046875, 621.425170898438, 637.431030273438, 638.433776855469, 
639.438354492188, 765.477722167969, 766.479309082031, 767.486633300781, 
781.471557617188, 782.475036621094, 783.487976074219, 784.491577148438, 
785.470153808594, 785.495300292969, 786.471923828125, 786.499084472656, 
799.483215332031, 800.483825683594, 801.487243652344, 945.54150390625, 
946.543395996094, 947.547241210938, 948.550903320312, 967.524230957031, 
968.524719238281, 981.518737792969, 982.519287109375, 983.517211914062, 
984.517639160156, 991.543334960938, 992.548278808594, 998.451721191406, 
999.459533691406, 1000.46405029297, 1009.54187011719, 1010.54992675781, 
1029.49401855469, 1030.50085449219)
```

(grouped data)

```
[1] 475.3794  476.3818  477.3875  
[2] 619.4194  620.4248  621.4252  
[3] 637.4310  638.4338  639.4384  
[4] 765.4777  766.4793  767.4866  
[5] 781.4716  782.4750  
[6] 783.4880  784.4916  785.4953  786.4991
[7] 785.4702  786.4719  
[8] 799.4832  800.4838  801.4872  
[9] 945.5415  946.5434  947.5472  948.5509  
[10] 967.5242  968.5247  
[11] 981.5187  982.5193  983.5172  984.5176  
[12] 991.5433  992.5483  
[13] 998.4517  999.4595 1000.4641 
[14] 1009.5419 1010.5499 
[15] 1029.4940 1030.5009
```

As you can find, each group has a specific differences (0.9983 to 1.0083)

Comment: Can you provide the data in easily copy&paste form (like `dput()`)?

Comment: sorry, change the form using dput()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a short solution without using any package

```
diff<-abs(x-lag(x))<1.0083
diff[1]<-TRUE
groups<-cumsum(ifelse(diff,0,1))
split(x,groups)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution using `dplyr` and creating diff values. You can adjust the diff threshold to suit your needs (I used value of 2):

```
library(dplyr)
v <- c(475.3794,  476.3818,  477.3875,  619.4194,  620.4248,  621.4252,  637.4310,  638.4338,  639.4384,  765.4777,  766.4793,  767.4866,  781.4716,  782.4750,  783.4880,  784.4916,  785.4702,  785.4953, 786.4719,  786.4991,  799.4832,  800.4838,  801.4872,  945.5415,  946.5434,  947.5472,  948.5509,  967.5242,  968.5247,  981.5187,  982.5193,  983.5172,  984.5176,  991.5433,  992.5483,  998.4517,  999.4595, 1000.4641, 1009.5419, 1010.5499, 1029.4940, 1030.5009)
df <- data.frame(v = v, diffv = c(0, diff(v)))
df %>% mutate(id = 1 + cumsum(diffv > 1.0083 | diffv < 0.9983)) %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(vlist = paste(v, collapse = ', '))
```

Output as follows. You can retrieve just the vlist column to get a list of vectors as you desire.

```
Source: local data frame [19 x 2]

      id                                  vlist
   (dbl)                                  (chr)
1      2           475.3794, 476.3818, 477.3875
2      3           619.4194, 620.4248, 621.4252
3      4            637.431, 638.4338, 639.4384
4      5           765.4777, 766.4793, 767.4866
5      6                      781.4716, 782.475
6      7                      783.488, 784.4916
7      8                               785.4702
8      9                               785.4953
9     10                               786.4719
10    11                               786.4991
11    12           799.4832, 800.4838, 801.4872
12    13 945.5415, 946.5434, 947.5472, 948.5509
13    14                     967.5242, 968.5247
14    15                     981.5187, 982.5193
15    16                     983.5172, 984.5176
16    17                     991.5433, 992.5483
17    18          998.4517, 999.4595, 1000.4641
18    19                   1009.5419, 1010.5499
19    20                    1029.494, 1030.5009
```

Comment: Thank you for your codes, but it can not separate row 5. It should be separated into two rows (783.4880  784.4916  785.4953  786.4991) and (785.4702  786.4719)

Comment: You can do that by tweaking the value 2 in that `mutate` part as I mentioned in my response. Change that to 1.1 or whatever will produce your desired buckets.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Correct. Using `arrange`  in the pipe will fix that problem.

Comment: @Inno: By what criterion should row 5 be separated into two buckets? (My solution also groups these values - I had assumed you made an error.) The distance between 785.4953 and 785.4702, which you want to be in separate buckets, is lower than any threshold (and lower than the distances *within* the buckets you want.)

Comment: @StephanKolassa: if some two values in my data have the difference between 0.9983 and 1.0083, they are grouped. Thus, in row 5, 785.4953 can be grouped with 784.4916 (diff: 1.0037) and 786.4991 (diff:1.0038), not 785.4702 (diff: 0.0251) and 786.4719 (diff: 0.9766).

Comment: @Inno: thank you. Then my answer doesn't solve your problem. Will delete it.

Comment: I fixed my mutate condition so it produces based on your desired range. Check and confirm. Otherwise, I can revise. Not sure where the miscommunication is on having to update the `mutate` condition to customize further to your needs.